# Why is pg_dump faster after rebooting?

Tags: linux, postgresql

When backing up my Postrgres database of 1.5GB using the following command:

pg_dump -U username database -f MM-DD-YY-backup.sql

It runs for 10 minutes or so and then I get a packet write wait / broken pipe (timeout). After logging back in to the server I check the files in the backup directory and the backup for today has a smaller filesize than yesterday's backup.

It gets really interesting when I reboot the server and then immediately run the backup command. The backup is created in about 30 seconds.

I really want to automate the backup process and the time difference before and after rebooting is a big concern. In my research, I haven't found anyone with similar experience which leads me to believe it could be a local setting on my machine which is causing pg_dump to take longer for the same operation after heavy use. After reboot, whatever resources that are freed up by the reboot become available again and it runs as expected.

Where should I start with debugging this?

Using Ubuntu 16.04.01, Postgres 9.5.4, 16GB of memory in the server.

Comment: It is just your shell that gets disconnected (caused by inactivity) Try running your backup in the background, eg `pg_dump -U username database -f MM-DD-YY-backup.sql &` , or `nohup pg_dump -U username database -f MM-DD-YY-backup.sql`

Comment: It could be concurrent activity. Are there any sessions refreshing materialized views, altering tables or other things that could create a longer ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock? Activate `log_lock_waits` and see if anything gets logged.